# Returning a matching key(different value) from an 2 associative arrays,

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

So lets say we have two arrays as such :

```
$x = array(
   "id" => 12,
   "name" => "Joe",
   "surname" => "Murphy",
   "age" => 52
);

$y = array(
   "id" => 12,
   "name" => "Joe",
   "surname" => "Murphy",
   "age" => 53
);

function key_compare_func($key1, $key2)
{
    if ($key1 == $key2)
        return 0;
    else if ($key1 > $key2)
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}

var_dump(array_intersect_ukey($x, $y, 'key_compare_func'));
```

This would return all matching elements from $x

```
array(4) { 
["id"]=> int(12) 
["name"]=> string(3) "Joe" 
["surname"]=> string(6) "Murphy" 
["age"]=> int(52) 
}
```

I need to get only  `["age"]=> int(52)`

I looked at these, but none seem to offer this sort of functionality, unless  I missed something :

> array_​udiff_​assoc, 
>   array_​uintersect_​assoc, 
>   array_​uintersect_​uassoc,
>   array_​udiffarray_​uintersect,
>   array_​udiff_​uassoc

Comment: Why do you only need `age` ? Is there a pattern behind this?

Comment: Since it is the only element which has `same key` but `different value`

Comment: What's wrong with `array_diff($x, $y);`? You didn't really explain the criteria of why that is the result.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php

```
var_dump(array_diff_assoc($x, $y));
```